# bare minimum PAT permission scope for az pipelines create command

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

what's the bare minimum permission scope for PAT to run "az pipelines create" command? When using "Full access", everything runs fine, but hard to figure out given so many option combinations. I couldn't find relevant documentation either. thanks!

I tried "full access", the "az pipelines create" runs fine. I would like to restrict the PAT to bare minimum permission scopes which is extremely time-consuming to do given so many scopes and options in each scope.